# How to communicate boolean values between programs from Arduino and Console

Tags: c++, arduino, serial-port

I am looking to communicate boolean values to and from two programs on arduino and windows console. I am working in C++ and using Visual Studio on the computer end and the standard arduino version of C++ on the arduino. All searches I have tried led me to using a windows form and a button on UI. I want this to all be done automatically and have both programs wait until the other has iterated. I've tried some Serial Port samples but none of them have worked so far for one reason or another. 
This is the console code I have:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int PIXEL_X = 1153;
const int PIXEL_Y = 636;

const int RED = 0;
const int BLUE = 50;
const int GREEN = 200;
const int TOLERANCE = 30;

int main(void) {
    COLORREF color;
    HDC hDC;

do {// Get the device context for the screen


    Sleep(50);

    hDC = GetDC(NULL);

    // Retrieve the color at that position
    color = GetPixel(hDC, PIXEL_X, PIXEL_Y);
    // Release the device context again
    ReleaseDC(GetDesktopWindow(), hDC);

    printf("%i %i %i", GetRValue(color), GetGValue(color), GetBValue(color));

    int flag = 0;

    if (fabs(GetRValue(color) - RED) > TOLERANCE) {
        flag += 1;
    }
    if (fabs(GetGValue(color) - GREEN) > TOLERANCE) {
        flag += 1;
    }
    if (fabs(GetBValue(color) - BLUE) > TOLERANCE) {
        flag += 1;
    }
    if (flag >= 2) {
        return 0;
    }

    //TODO 1: Send Serial data to continue and wait for return statement

} while (true);
return 0;
```

}

EDIT: This is my arduino code

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo myServo;
Servo myServo2;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  myServo.attach(2);
  myServo2.attach(3);
}

void A_button() {
  myServo.write(125);
  delay(1000);
  myServo.write(97);
  delay(250);
}

void L_button() {
  myServo2.write(72);
  delay(1000);
  myServo2.write(90);
  delay(250);
}

void loop() {

  for(int i=0; i < 16; i++) {
    A_button();
    Serial.print("1 ");
    delay(1500);
  }
  delay(3000);

  // TODO 2: send Serial data

  L_button();
  Serial.print("0 ");
}
```

EDIT: Thank you for the response. I want the console application code to wait until the arduino code goes to TODO 2, then the console application runs until TODO 1 and checks if the RGB values are in their tolerances. If the RGB values are within the tolrance, then I want the arduino code to continue iterating until the TODO 2 again and repeat. I don't have any C++ code for the serial communication because none of the examples I've tried have compiled, and I can't use a windows form as I understand it.

I want to have the code wait at the TODO, but I have absolutely no idea how to do this and would appreciate any help. I will elaborate if any needs me to.
Thank you in advance.